# How to debug django-excel zero output + no error?

Tags: pyexcel, django-excel

I need a simple data-export from a Django app to xls. I set up django-excel and files are generated/downloaded but with 0 kB / no content.

There is no error message and there are tons of objects for the model I am trying to export. My code looks like this:

```
def export_data(request, atype):
    if atype == "sheet":
        return excel.make_response_from_a_table(City, 'xls', file_name="cities")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I had django-parler installed which django-excel wasn't compatible with or rather I didn't try to make then work together.